# Do I have to use dot notation in Objective C to access structure values?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I've searched all over for an answer to this simple question, with no luck. So here it is: Is it possible to access an Object's structure values in Objective-C without using dot notation, i.e., using only the canonical message syntax?  E.g., let's say that we have a CGPoint instance variable, position, defined for a Particle object:

```
//Particle.h
@interface Particle : NSObject {
CGPoint position
}
@property CGPoint position;
@end
```

and the corresponding implementation:

```
//Particle.m
#import "Particle.h"
@implementation Particle
@synthesize position;
@end
```

And suppose that in some other *.m file (say AppController.m) we have:

```
a_particle = [Particle alloc];
[a_particle setPosition:CGPointMake(x_val,y_val)];
```

Then why can't we use:

```
[[a_particle position] x];
```

to get x_val rather than:

```
a_paticle.position.x;
```

noting that the latter works fine? Note also that

```
[a_particle position].x;
```

will work, but I am trying to avoid cluttering things up with dot notation. My hunch is that a structure instance variable MUST use dot notation to access its values (in this case x_val and y_val), is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `CGPoint` is just a plain old C `struct`, not an objective-c class so you can't send messages to it. You need to use C's syntax for reading struct members, ie the '.'

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected but was trying to avoid cluttering up my code with dots.

Comment: It's not clutter, it's just the C language.

Answer (score 5):

Structures are from C and therefore must be accessed using tradition C methods. You access a struct's fields using a `.` or de-reference them using `->` and that's the only way to do it. Passing messages is an Objective-C thing and doesn't really make sense because they're not actually an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. The member operator is a C operator for accessing members of `structs`.

Objective-C methods only operate on Objective-C types, therefore it is not possible for this same method invocation syntax to work on `struct` values, which are ***not*** Objective-C types.

(Unless the Objective-C runtime supported it, which it currently does not, and I hope will not do so in the future.)

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I like your explanation too.